# Accessing table values using relative XPath in Python

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to find a relative Xpath (not absolute Xpath) that will allow me to extract data from this url: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000228/000100022810000006/the10k_2009.htm

My code is below. SalesB returns a value ('233,715') but SalesA returns empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
from lxml import html
import requests

SEC_pageA = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000228/000100022810000006/the10k_2009.htm')
SEC_treeA = html.fromstring(SEC_pageA.content)
SalesA = SEC_treeA.xpath('(//p[contains(., "CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF INCOME")]/following::td[contains(.,"Net sales")]/following-sibling::td[@align="right"]//text())[1]')

SEC_pageB = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312515356351/d17062d10k.htm')
SEC_treeB = html.fromstring(SEC_pageB.content)
SalesB = SEC_treeB.xpath('(//p[contains(., "CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF OPERATIONS")]/following::td[contains(.,"Net sales")]/following-sibling::td[@align="right"]//text())[1]')

print SalesA
print SalesB
```

SalesB returns the value shown below, which can be found via the SEC_pageA variable (see https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000119312515356351/d17062d10k.htm).

[image]

I want SalesA to return the 'Net sales' figure which can be seen below (ie. 6,538,336) and found here: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000228/000100022810000006/the10k_2009.htm

[image]

Comment: might help to use the developer tools in something like Chrome to inspect the element and find path info about it.   I suspect that type of page is so much about formatting vs data organization that xpath is probably going to be limited in its usefulness. also. you might try loading the source of the page in something like eclipse then use an xpath exploration plugin to try path statements to get to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Its because some text are not in one line, due to that xpath could not find what you really want.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

xpath_a = """
//*[text()[contains(., "CONSOLIDATED
      STATEMENTS OF INCOME")]]/following::td[contains(., "Net
      sales")][1]/following-sibling::td[@valign="bottom"][3]//text()
      """

SEC_pageA = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1000228/000100022810000006/the10k_2009.htm')
SEC_treeA = html.fromstring(SEC_pageA.content)
SalesA = SEC_treeA.xpath(xpath_a)

print(SalesA)
```

prints

```
['6,538,336']
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks that's really helpful. Is there a way I could select nodes that contain values similar to 'CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF INCOME', such that the code ignores the spaces?

Comment: PS - I'd like it to ignore the spaces for both 'CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF INCOME' and 'Net sales'

Comment: maybe you can use beautifulsoup